# Stripe Invoice strategy for multiple products

Tags: workflow, stripe-payments

I'm wondering how I should (must ?) implement stripe invoice in case my customer buy multiple products.

Should I create an invoice for total amount ?
Should I create invoice items for each product and then create an invoice to charge all these products ?

Advantages of second solution would be I won't have to store which products have been bought.

I'm interesting knowing what are your workflows and what you think about it !

Comment: I wouldn't use Invoices for that but a one-time charge and then store the content of the order on your own backend